# getting ResultSet's values dynamically

Tags: java, resultset

Is there any way to get ResultSet's values dynamically? here is the code below to make my question clear.

```
while(rsltSet.next())
{
arr[i][0] = rsltSet.getInt(1)+"";
arr[i][1] = rsltSet.getInt(2)+"";
arr[i][2] = rsltSet.getString(3)+"";
arr[i][3] = rsltSet.getString(4)+"";
arr[i][4] = rsltSet.getString(5)+"";
}
```

I tried to use  code below in a for loop, it gave me an exception which I cannot get the detail of.

```
for(int j=1;j<columnCount;j++)
     arr[i][j] = rslt2.getObject(j)+"";
```

How can I get the values of ResultSet without specifyinh whether it is integer or string or date?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You have to know what they are to ever do anything with them.  I guess you could throw them into an un-typed (new word!) ArrayList, but that's a terrible idea, and you would still have to know what type they are to pull them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the type info use the [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) from the [ResultSet.getMetaData()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) call. Otherwise, you can always use getObject(j).toString().